# Ansible есть одна группа хостов, для каждого сервера разная команда, как написать плейбук?

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

подскажите пожалуйста, как написать плейбук, задача и проблема такова: для каждого определенного айпишника мне надо вводить свою команду, скажем на рестарт процесса в пм2, и для каждого сервера идет свое имя сертификата:
hosts example=>

```
[hosts]
204.98.184.89 ansible_user=ansible
202.233.23.238 ansible_user=ansible
243.19.114.128 ansible_user=ansible
217.160.12.156 ansible_user=ansible
165.174.53.252 ansible_user=ansible
```

```
NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS='/home/certb1.pem' pm2 restart
NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS='/home/certb2.pem' pm2 restart
NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS='/home/certb3.pem' pm2 restart
NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS='/home/certv1.pem' pm2 restart
NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS='/home/certv2.pem' pm2 restart
```

буду благодарен любой помощи, спасибо!

Comment: Создайте переменную в host_vars для каждого хоста (или в group_vars для групп хостов) и используйте эту переменную в плейбуке